# R: Using a vector to feed dataframe names for sapply

Tags: r, loops

I'm quite new to R, and I trying to use it to organize and extract info from some tables into different, but similar tables, and instead of repeating the commands but changing the names of the table:

```
#DvE, DvS, and EvS are dataframes
Sum.DvE <- data.frame(DvE$genes, DvE$FDR, DvE$logFC)
names(Sum.DvE) <- c("gene","FDR","log2FC")
Sum.DvS <- data.frame(DvS$genes, DvS$FDR, DvS$logFC)
names(Sum.DvS) <- c("gene","FDR","log2FC")
Sum.EvS <- data.frame(EvS$genes, EvS$FDR, EvS$logFC)
names(Sum.EvS) <- c("gene","FDR","log2FC")
```

I thought it would be easier to create a vector of the table names, and feed it into a for loop:

```
Sum.Comp <- c("DvE","DvS","EvS")
for(i in 1:3){
  Sum.Comp[i] <- data.frame(i$genes, i$FDR, i$logFC)
  names(Sum.Comp[i]) <- c("gene","FDR","log2FC")
}
```

But I get

```
>Error in i$genes : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

which I kind of expected because I was just trying it out, but can someone tell me if what I want to do can be done some other way, or if you have some suggestions for me, that would be much appreciated!

Clarification: Basically I'm trying to ask if there's a way to feed a dataframe name into a for loop through a vector, because I think I get the error because R doesn't realize "i" in the for loop stands for a dataframe name. This is a more simplified example:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(A=1:5, B=1:5, C=1:5, D=1:5)
DF2 <- data.frame(A=10:15, B=10:15, C=10:15, D=10:15)
DF3 <- data.frame(A=20:25, B=20:25, D=20:25, D=20:25)

DFs <- ("DF1", "DF2", "DF3")

for (i in 1:3){
    New.i <- dataframe(i$A, i$D)
}
```

And I'd like it to make 3 new dataframes called "New.DF1", "New.DF2", "New.DF3" with example outputs like:

```
New.DF1
    A   D
    1   1   
    2   2
    3   3
    4   4
    5   5

New.DF2
    A   D
    10  10  
    11  11
    12  12
    13  13
    14  14  
    15  15
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your goal? To assign the same names to a bunch of different data.frames? Or something else?

Comment: Sample input and output please. It's not entirely clear what you are working with or what you want to achieve. I sense that you might be looking for indexing by `[row, column]` rather than by `$`.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have posted a less complicated example. The goal of what I'm trying to do with the tables wasn't the focus of my question, as I'm trying to ask how can I make the for loop recognize "i" is a dataframe and not just a string? I've updated the question with a simplified examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand your problem, but the code below may do what you're asking.  I've created simple values for the input data frames for testing.

```
DvE <- data.frame(genes=1:2, FDR=2:3, logFC=3:4)
DvS <- data.frame(genes=4, FDR=5, logFC=6)
EvS <- data.frame(genes=7, FDR=8, logFC=9)

df_names <- c("DvE","DvS",  "EvS")

sum_df <- function(x) data.frame(gene=x$genes, FDR=x$FDR, log2FC=x$logFC)

for(df in df_names)  {
   assign(paste("Sum.",df,sep=""), do.call("sum_df", list(as.name(df)) ) )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This totally does what I want it to!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of operating on the names of variables, it would be easier to store the data frames you want to process in a list and then process them with `lapply`:

```
to.process <- list(DvE, DvS, EvS)
processed <- lapply(to.process, function(x) {
  data.frame(gene=x$genes, FDR=x$FDR, log2FC=x$logFC)
})
```

Now you can access the new data frames with `processed[[1]]`, `processed[[2]]`, and `processed[[3]]`.

Comment: Thanks! your way works too, but I'd need extra steps to separate the different dataframes in processed.

Comment: @Fenrir usually when I've wanted to do this sort of thing I would want to apply the same analysis to each of the data frames, so the list output is actually more convenient (I can use `lapply` on the list). If that's not the case for you, then yeah @WaltS's approach seems to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks josiber. I like your way too, but I just need that extra step to separate the different dataframes, and I like WaltS's way in that the separated dataframes was sort of automatically named in the process. I suppose there's probably an easy to add in that extra step (of separating the dataframes). But I'm still very new to R and I appreciate different comments and advice :D Thanks so much!

Comment: Since you've explained that you're new to R, I should mention that the method I showed, creating separate dataframes for related sets of data, is unusual.  Bringing these dataframes together for processing can then be a bit like herding proverbial cats. josilber's method of combining them in a list would be a more typical approach.  Since the dataframes have compatible columns, another common method is to combine them into one large dataframe with an added column containing an identifier for the source.  In the end,however, you know your problem and should choose whichever works best for you.